# Windows 7 alarm clock

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, time-management

I'm looking for a Windows 7 alarm clock with:

- An alarm that I cannot miss, even when I have been away from the computer;
   I guess that leaves only an always-on-top dialog.
- No presence on the desktop (like a visual clock) until the alarm goes off
  (I'm not using any sidebar either)
- <strike>Preferably no presence in the system tray</strike> *Not really an issue in Win 7*
- Free
- Repeating alarms for schedules like 'every wednesday' and 'every mon/tue/thu/friday'

Basically, *I don't want to know it's running* together with *It's impossible to miss that the alarm goes/went off*.

I was [using the Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.howtogeek.com/120566/how-to-create-a-repeating-alarm-in-windows-7-without-extra-software/) with a dialog message, but that popped up under my virtual machine (maybe just when I was switching windows), so I missed it.

Extra bonus points for supplying a link to an installer that does not install additional cr*p on my system, like the downloaders from the larger 'software tools' sites do nowadays.

Comment: In Windows 7, there's a way to hide system tray icons.  Check for a "Notification Area Icons" control panel.  If you want to install a tool without getting any adware or toolbars along with it, use Chocolatey to install it (if a Chocolatey package for that tool is available).

Comment: What do you want to use the alarm clock for?  Also, do you routinely carry a cellphone of any sort in your pocket?

Comment: @unforgettableid 1) I have edited out the system tray requirement because that's hardly an issue in Win 7 2) "Shut down and go - it's time to catch your bus" 3) If I ask for Windows I'm not interested in answers for cellphones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend an application called Desktop Reminder. I have been using it now for about 6 months and I love it. It has an extremely simple and easy to use interface but a lot of advanced features when needed. In regard to your requirements,

- When there is an alarm, your computer will sound and a popup will come up on your desktop above all other windows, can't miss it.
- There is no presence and sits in the background taking up very little memory.
- There is a tiny icon in the system tray, it doesn't flash or change colors. Also, @unforgettableid gave a way to hide it
- There is a free and pro version. I would have stuck with the free version (as it does basically everything I need it too and meets your requirements) *but* once you hear the alarm sound (sounds can only be changed in the pro version) you may want to upgrade:)
- Not only can you do daily repeating but basically any kind of repeating you can think of from biyearly to certain months of certain days.

Again, it hides in the background and you will definitely know when it's going off
Installer does not add any cr*p with it, I hate that too

> ## [Desktop-Reminder](http://www.desktop-reminder.com/en/index.html)
>
> Desktop-Reminder is a FREEWARE task planner for Windows to manage your tasks and other to-dos’ in an easy way. It can start with Windows and list all tasks, which are urgent for the current day. For a task with time of day defined a corresponding alarm message will be shown, when the time comes.
>
> [image: Desktop Reminder UI]

Comment: In case anyone missed it: There is a portable version hidden on the site. [Scroll down to the end](http://www.desktop-reminder.com/en/download/index.html)

Comment: That works nicely and I can live with the sound (after your remark I thought it was going to be something horribly loud).

Comment: Two minor annoyances: 1) It is a bit sluggish (when I first started it I wondered 'Hey, I started it, why does it now show?' and starting closing other windows 'Maybe it's behind those?' and then it finally popped up), and 2) It insists that the start of the recurring pattern is in the recurring pattern. On Thursday I started a weekly recurring task to happen on Wednesdays, and I could not uncheck the 'Thursday' box. Most schedulers don't care if the start of your recurrence pattern is outside of the actual coccurences. I have reported these to the author.

Comment: It seems reasonable fast with my computer but that is a good point with recurring pattern, I have not yet noticed that. The author; though, updates the software frequently, I'm sure that will be fixed